# Google Map not working in Intel xdk emulator but working fine in any browser using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am creating an app which tracks user location and mark multiple markers on the map.

Although my app is working fine on browsers but not working in Intel XDK Emulator and Mobiles.

Cordova CLI Version : 5.4.1
Intel XDK Version : 3240

below is my code :

```
function currentpostionmap() {
    $(document).on("pageshow", "#inside123", function () {

         
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    
            function success(pos) {            
                userClat = pos.coords.latitude;
                userClng = pos.coords.longitude;
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude); 
                var myOptions = {            
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    zoomControl:true,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,        
                };        
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);      
                var image123 = 'https:///developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
                //                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();        
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({            
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: image123                
                });

                var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow1.setContent('YOU');
                        infowindow1.open(map, marker);
                        map.setZoom(20);
                        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

                    }
                })(marker));

                multimarker(map, latlng, infowindow1);        
            }        
            function fail(error) {          
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5204, 73.8567); 
                var myOptions = {            
                    zoom: 10,
                                center: latlng,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP        
                };        
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);             
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({            
                    position: latlng,
                                map: map                   
                });


                        
            }       
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {
                maximumAge: 500000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 6000
            });    
        }
    });

}
function getlocation()
{
        if (navigator != null) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

        function success(position) {

            userClat = position.coords.latitude;
            userClng = position.coords.longitude;             
            goToLogin();    

        }

        function fail(error) {
            if (error.code == PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                alert("App doesn't have permission to use GPS");
            } else if (error.code == PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE) {
                alert("No GPS device found");
            } else if (error.code == PositionError.TIMEOUT) {
                alert("Its taking too much time to find user location");
            } else {
                alert("An unknown error occured");
            }
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {
            maximumAge: 500,
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 600
        });


    }
        }
    else
        {
            console.log ('NAVIGATOR ERROR');
        }
}


function multimarker(map, userloc, infowindow) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "getdriverlocation.php",

        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            data = $.trim(data);
            if (data == "false") {
                $('#footInfo').html('<p>No Driver Registered</p>');


            } else {
                //        console.log(data)
                var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // instead of JSON.parse(data)

                jQuery(myArray).each(function (index, element) {
                    driverlat = element.driver_lat;
                    driverlng = element.driver_lng;
                    loginid = element.loginid;
                    locations.push([driverlat, driverlng, loginid])
                });
                var bounds1 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                    var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
                    if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng1, map.getCenter()) < 30000) {
                        drivermarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng1,
                            icon: "img/car.png",
                            map: map
                        });
                        drivermarker.setMap(map);

                        google.maps.event.addListener(drivermarker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function (evt) {
                                //        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
                                //        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                driverdetail(locations[i][2]);
                            }
                        })(drivermarker, i));
                        bounds1.extend(latlng1);
                        map.fitBounds(bounds1);
                    }
                }
                bounds1.extend(userloc);
                map.fitBounds(bounds1);
                // wait for the bounds change to happen
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
                    // set the center on the user
                    map.setCenter(userloc);
                    // wait for the center to change
                    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
                        // check to see if all the markers are still in bounds
                        if ((!map.getBounds().contains(bounds1.getNorthEast())) ||
                            (!map.getBounds().contains(bounds1.getSouthWest()))) {
                            // if not zoom out one level
                            //                        console.log(map.getZoom() + " zoom-1 will be " + (map.getZoom() - 1));
                            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", currentpostionmap);

function watchDriverPosition(userid) {

    $(document).on("pageshow", "#drivermain", function () { 
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            function success(position) {

                window.setInterval(function () {
                    updateDriverLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, userid);
                }, 50000);
            }

            function fail(error) {
                if (error.code == PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    alert("App doesn't have permission to use GPS");
                } else if (error.code == PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE) {
                    alert("No GPS device found");
                } else if (error.code == PositionError.TIMEOUT) {
                    alert("Its taking to find user location");
                } else {
                    alert("An unknown error occured");
                }
            }
            watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, fail, {
                maximumAge: 500000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 6000
            });
        }
    });
}



 $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready!");

        getlocation();

    });
```

Whenever the app starts on emulator, it is giving me two alerts first is

> Its taking to find user location

Second is

> An unknown error occured

This is my first mobile app I really worked hard to reach this much, please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

with Intel XDK and Cordova some features must be run with some scripts provided by the proper intel xdk library.

In the case of geolocation you must invoke it with this call

intel.xdk.geolocation.watchPosition(suc,fail,options);

and here is an example code

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/article/intel-xdk-geolocation-sample

Note that for example uploading images by accessing to mobile or camera needs something similar, so in html running directly on browser you can access the camera or file browser but not in cordova and xdk packed app that needs to access to the hardware.

Hope this helps you

Comment: It is not working I have changed the `navigator.geolocation` to `intel.xdk.geolocation` then also it is not wrking

Comment: Because it's not only necessary to call the function. Must read all documentation.